# Can I use same reportviewer to show local and server reports?

Tags: c#, reporting

I am wondering can I use same reportviewer to show local and server reports?

So most of my reports are local I want just one made in report builder to show on same report viewer where local reports are shown, now I am wondering how I can do that? Here is what I've tried:

```
switch (btnID)
            {
                case 1:
                    reportViewerZarada.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "MIS_p18.Reports.rptNetoZarada.rdlc";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    reportViewerZarada.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "MIS_p18.Reports.rptBrutoZarada.rdlc";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    reportViewerZarada.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://localhost/reportserver");
                    reportViewerZarada.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/p18report/TabelaZarade";
                    break;
```

But I get this result on case 3:

> The source of report definition has not been specified